# Typeform Security API and Django: Not Verifiying Hash Correctly

Tags: django, ruby, hash, webhooks, typeform

I am trying to use Typeform's security for their webhooks. This involves

```
1) Receiving the signed packets and extracting the signature
2) Getting the body of the requst
3) Creating a hash with a secret key on the payload
4) Matching the hash with the received signature
```

My web framework is Django (Python based). I am following the example at the TypeForm link here: https://developer.typeform.com/webhooks/secure-your-webhooks/.

For the life of me, I can't figure out what's going on. I've tried it in both Python and Ruby, and I can't get the hash right. I call a Ruby script from Python to match the output, but they are different and neither work. Does anyone have any insight? I'm starting to think that it might have something to do with the way that Django sends request bodies. Does anyone have any input?

Python implementation:

```
import os
import hashlib
import hmac
import base64
import json


class Typeform_Verify:
    # take the request body in and encrypt with string
    def create_hash(payload):
        # convert the secret string to bytes 
        file = open("/payload.txt", "w") 
        # write to a payload file for the ruby script to read later
        file.write(str(payload))
        # access the secret string
        secret = bytearray(os.environ['DT_TYPEFORM_STRING'], encoding="utf-8")
        file.close()
        # need to have the ruby version also write to a file
        # create a hash with payload as the thing 
        #   and the secret as the key`
        pre_encode = hmac.new(secret,
            msg=payload, digestmod=hashlib.sha256).digest()
        post_encode = base64.b64encode(pre_encode)
        return post_encode

    # another approach is to make a ruby script 
    #   that returns a value and call it from here
    def verify(request):
        file = open("/output.txt", "w")
        # check the incoming hash values
        received_hash = request.META["HTTP_TYPEFORM_SIGNATURE"] 
        # create the hash of the payload
        hash = Typeform_Verify.create_hash(request.body)
        # call ruby script on it
        os.system(f"ruby manager/ruby_version.rb {received_hash} &> /oops.txt") 
        # concatenate the strings together to make the hash
        encoded_hash = "sha256=" + hash.decode("utf-8")
        file.write(f"Secret string: {os.environ['DT_TYPEFORM_STRING']}\n")
        file.write(f"My hash    : {encoded_hash}\n")
        file.write(f"Their hash : {received_hash}\n")
        file.close()
        return received_hash == encoded_hash
```

Ruby script (called from Python)

```
require 'openssl'
require 'base64'
require 'rack'
def verify_signature(received_signature, payload_body, secret)
  hash = OpenSSL::HMAC.digest(OpenSSL::Digest.new('sha256'), secret, payload_body)
  # the created signature
  actual_signature = 'sha256=' + Base64.strict_encode64(hash) 
  # write created signature to the file
  out_file = File.new("/output.txt", "a")
  out_file.write("Ruby output: ")
  out_file.write(actual_signature)
  out_file.close()
  return 500, "Signatures don't match!" unless Rack::Utils.secure_compare(actual_signature, received_signature)
end

# MAIN EXECUTION 
# get the hash from the python scriupt
received_hash = ARGV[0]
# read the content of the file into the f array 
    # note that this is the json payload from the python script
f = IO.readlines("/payload.txt")
# declare the secret string
secret = "SECRET"
# call the funtion with the recieved hash, file data, and key
result = verify_signature(received_hash, f[0], secret)
```

Code output:

```
Typeform hash:   sha256=u/A/F6u3jnG9mr8KZH6j8/gO+Uny6YbSYFz7+oGmOik=
Python hash:     sha256=sq7Kl2qBwRrwgGJeND6my4UPli8rseuwaK+f/sl8dko=
Ruby output:     sha256=BzMxPZGmxgOMeJ236eAxSOXj85rEWI84t+6CtQBYliA=
```

Comment: in ruby you have `secret =` and a hard coded string... can that be correct?  And if so, you probably don't want to publish this here right? But also, Shouldn't `f[0]` be `f[1]`  ?

Comment: You're totally right I don't want that here at all. I removed that. Also, f[0] should stay like that because it's the first and only line in a file. The file contains the JSON data written from the Python script without newline chars so it's all in 1 line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up figuring it out. The Python implementation I had worked fine. The problem was in how I was saving the secret string. Apparently, environment variables in Python will not allow characters like $ or *. My Ruby implementation started working when I hardcoded my secret into the code, which led me to believe that the problem was in how I was saving the secret string. I recommend the Python implementation to anyone trying to do this kind of authentication. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

UPDATED First see [this github article](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/securing/) as the one you referred to may be based on it.

The idea is that your requests should be signed.  Here is a more basic pure ruby example which should illustrate how this should work.

```
# test.rb
ENV['SECRET_TOKEN'] = 'foobar'
require 'openssl'
require 'base64'
require 'rack'

def stub_request(body)
  key = ENV['SECRET_TOKEN']
  digest = OpenSSL::Digest.new('sha256')
  hmac_signature = OpenSSL::HMAC.hexdigest(digest, key, body)
  { body: body, hmac_signature: hmac_signature }
end

def verify_signature(payload_body, request_signature)
  digest = OpenSSL::Digest.new('sha256')
  hmac = OpenSSL::HMAC.hexdigest(OpenSSL::Digest.new('sha256'), ENV['SECRET_TOKEN'], payload_body)
  if Rack::Utils.secure_compare(request_signature, hmac)
    puts "They match"
  else
    puts "They don't match"
  end
  puts "request_signature: #{request_signature}"
  puts "             hmac: #{hmac}"
  puts "             body: #{payload_body}"
end

request = stub_request(ARGV[0])
verify_signature(request[:body], request[:hmac_signature])
```

Now to test this, just run:

```
ruby test.rb 'this is some random body string'
```

Here is a Python version of the same code.  But this is vulnerable to [timing attack vulnerability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timing_attack).  There is probably a Python equivalent somewhere to mitigate this but I didn't do the research to find it.  It shouldn't be hard to write something like the [Ruby Rack version here](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/master/lib/rack/utils.rb#L379) in Python if your server doesn't already have something like it.

```
#test.py
import sys
import hashlib
import binascii
import hmac
import base64

KEY = 'foobar'

def stub_request(body):
    key = bytes(KEY, 'utf-8')
    body_bytes = bytes(body, 'utf-8')
    hmac_signature = hmac.new(key,
        msg=body_bytes, digestmod=hashlib.sha256).digest()
    return {'body': body, 'hmac_signature': hmac_signature}

def verify_signature(payload_body, request_signature):
    key = bytes(KEY, 'utf-8')
    hmac_sig = hmac.new(key, msg=bytes(payload_body,'utf-8'), digestmod=hashlib.sha256).digest()

    if hmac_sig == request_signature:
        print("They match")
    else  :
        print("They don't match")

    print(f"request_signature: {binascii.hexlify(request_signature)}")
    print(f"             hmac: {binascii.hexlify(hmac_sig)}")
    print(f"             body: {payload_body}")
    return request_signature

body = sys.argv[-1]
request = stub_request(body)
verify_signature(request['body'], request['hmac_signature'])
```

Comment: No that's not right because I write to payload.txt in my Python script as in   file = open("/payload.txt", "w")  file.write(str(payload))

Comment: Yes, I see.  See my updated answer, hopefully this helps.

Comment: Ok, that's fair as a Ruby implementation. Is there a resource you could point me in for a Python one? My framework is Python based.

Comment: I updated again to give you a working basic python example similar to the ruby one I've provide here as proof of concept.

Comment: Also you might have a look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/signing/